# Python keeps returning list index out of range?

Tags: python

I have the following class that checks for all available moves in a game- basically what it does is return the array positions in all 8 directions of any placed blocks (w or b) and removes the ones that are currently occupied by a w or b block-

```
class Game():    
 def _available_moves(self):
        ''' generate available moves '''
        self.board = [['','','','','',''],['','','','','',''],['','','b','w','',''],['','','w','b','',''],['','','','','',''],['','','','','','']]
        potential_moves = []
        player = "w"
        second_player = "b"
        for row_num in range(0,len(self.board)):
            for col_num in range(0,len(self.board[row_num])):
                if(self.board[row_num][col_num]==second_player):
                    potential_moves.append([row_num-1,col_num])
                    potential_moves.append([row_num+1,col_num])
                    potential_moves.append([row_num,col_num+1])
                    potential_moves.append([row_num,col_num-1])
                    potential_moves.append([row_num+1,col_num+1])
                    potential_moves.append([row_num-1,col_num+1])
                    potential_moves.append([row_num+1,col_num-1])
                    potential_moves.append([row_num-1,col_num-1])
        print(potential_moves)                    
        for move in range(0,len(potential_moves)):
            move_1 = potential_moves[move][0]
            move_2 = potential_moves[move][1]
            if(self.board[move_1][move_2]=="w" or self.board[move_1][move_2]=="b"):
                del potential_moves[move]
            move_1 = ""
            move_2 = ""
        return potential_moves
```

This keeps giving me `IndexError: list index out of range` however when I try it in the console, there isn't any error:

```
>>> potential_moves = [[2, 4], [4, 4], [3, 5], [3, 3], [4, 5], [2, 5], [4, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3], [5, 3], [4, 4], [4, 2], [5, 4], [3, 4], [5, 2], [3, 2]]
>>> for move in range(0,len(potential_moves)):
            move_1 = potential_moves[move][0]


>>> move_1
3
```

I think the "move" index in the for loop is what's messing it up- but I'm not sure.

A full traceback is shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karan/Desktop/othello.py", line 202, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "C:/Users/Karan/Desktop/othello.py", line 199, in run_game
    othello._do_turn()
  File "C:/Users/Karan/Desktop/othello.py", line 119, in _do_turn
    self._make_move(current_turn,_translate_move(user_turn_input))
  File "C:/Users/Karan/Desktop/othello.py", line 155, in _make_move
    if([move_row, move_col] in self._available_moves()):
  File "C:/Users/Karan/Desktop/othello.py", line 141, in _available_moves
    move_1 = potential_moves[move][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The function is on lines 121 - 148, approx (made some alterations for readability)

Edit:

I updated the code as per suggestions, changing to:

```
for move in range(0,len(potential_moves)):
    if(self.board[potential_moves[move][0]][potential_moves[move][1]]=="w" or self.board[potential_moves[move][0]][potential_moves[move][1]]=="b"):
        del potential_moves[move]
        potential_moves.append("")
print(potential_moves)
return potential_moves
```

but now I'm getting an even stranger error?

```
    if(self.board[potential_moves[move][0]][potential_moves[move][1]]=="w" or self.board[potential_moves[move][0]][potential_moves[move][1]]=="b"):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?  And what line is that in your code?  A full trace would be more helpful than just the error.

Comment: Can you give us there error traceback? what for loop is running out of range? EDIT: yeah. what @jedwards said. (He beat me)

Comment: @jedwards I added in the traceback at the bottom! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the bigger purpose for deleting elements, but if you're looping over a list by length, when you modify a list by deleting elements, running out of bounds makes sense.

In other words, in this block:

```
for move in range(0,len(potential_moves)):
    move_1 = potential_moves[move][0]
    move_2 = potential_moves[move][1]
    if(self.board[move_1][move_2]=="w" or self.board[move_1][move_2]=="b"):
        del potential_moves[move]
    move_1 = ""
    move_2 = ""
```

You're "locking in" the number of iterations through the loop at the start, but then modifying the list.

I suspect deleting the item isn't really what you want, but without more context it's hard to say what might be more appropriate.

If you ***really*** want to delete elements in the list, you can iterate over it in a safer way as follows:

```
for (move,(move_1, move_2)) in enumerate(potential_moves):
    if(self.board[move_1][move_2]=="w" or self.board[move_1][move_2]=="b"):
        del potential_moves[move]
```

This will respect deletion of the current element.

EDIT:

Just for fun, this could be re-written using `in` as:

```
for (move,(move_1, move_2)) in enumerate(potential_moves):
    if(self.board[move_1][move_2] in ["w", "b"]):
        del potential_moves[move]
```

Comment: Happy to help, I added an edit at the bottom that might show you another cool feature of python that may help in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If I look at your code, I see one major factor that could be causing the issue you are having:

```
if(self.board[move_1][move_2]=="w" or self.board[move_1][move_2]=="b"):
    del potential_moves[move]
```

When you delete an object out of your list, you shorten your list by one... but that doesn't get updated in the beginning of your `for` loop.

```
for move in range(0,len(potential_moves)):
```

This loop got the length of your list *Before the `for` loop started*. That means that if you change the size of your list within the scope of the loop, you will get to the end of your list before your `for` loop completes.

The reason this didn't occur in the console is that you didn't have the `del` statement in your console example. I'm willing to bet that if you added that part in you would get the exact same error.

A possible way to fix this could be appending `None` objects onto the end of the list whenever you delete something, and then removing those from the list once you are done with the `for` loop.

Comment: I tried this and updated the question with what's happening! Thank you so much though! :-)

Comment: @KaranK You're adding an empty string, and then later trying to get the second element in that string. it's the same as trying to get the second element in a list. Try using the keyword `None` or adding a precursor `if` statement that says that if the string does not equal "" then do the original if statement.